# Logback default value when runtime parameter is not supplied

Tags: logging, logback

I have this conf in my logback.xml:

```
<logger name="L1" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="${SELECTED_CONSOLE}" />
</logger>

<root level="${LOG_LEVEL}">
    <appender-ref ref="${SELECTED_CONSOLE}" />
</root>
```

My issue is, on some env, if the LOG_LEVEL var hasn't been defined, what will the level of log of L1 be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `LOG_LEVEL` parameter is undefined then Logback will treat that as this string:

```
LOG_LEVEL_IS_UNDEFINED
```

Logback will then turn that value into `ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG` (see the implementation of `ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.toLevel()`)

So, your root logger level will be `DEBUG` and since the L1 logger has no level declared it will inherit that level. So, if `LOG_LEVEL` is not defined then the log level for L1 will be: `DEBUG`.

The fact that L1's additivity is false does not change this; additivity prevents parents of the L1 logger from using their appenders to display the message, it does not affect the inferred log level.